# Session variables in iOS app

Tags: php, ios

I have been trying to get help on using Session variables in an iOS app. The more I have searched, the more confused I have become. Some people saying just store user data in NSUserDefaults, others say send tokens in Auth Header and still more people say to use the Session class method and call it from each class

Unfortunately now I have no idea what I am supposed to be doing. I have a login script that is working correctly and is setting the $_SESSION variables, I just don't know how to use those variables once back in the app.

**EDIT FOR CLARITY**

OK what I actually need is a way to echo the $_SESSION variables into my app and then access that information. I have seen information about NSCookieStorage and the fact that it stores cookies automatically is this correct? if so, how do i use it? do I have to echo the results back to populate the cookie or is there a cookie automatically sent when the login success comes back?

login script

```
//
//  LoginViewController.m
//  TESG-iConnect
//
//  Created by TESG on 5/03/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 TESG. All rights reserved.
//
#import "LoginViewController.h"



@interface LoginViewController ()

@end


@implementation LoginViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (IBAction)signinClicked:(id)sender {
        NSInteger success = 0;
        @try {

            if([[self.txtUsername text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {

                [self alertStatus:@"Please enter TESG Portal Username and Password" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];

            } else {
                NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[self.txtUsername text],[self.txtPassword text]];
                NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

                NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tesg.com.au/loginJson.php"];

                NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

                NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                [request setURL:url];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
                [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
                [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                [request setHTTPBody:postData];

                //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

                NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
                NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
                NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

                NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

                if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
                {
                    NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

                    NSError *error = nil;
                    NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                              JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                              error:&error];

                    success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];
                    NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);

                    if(success == 1)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                    } else {

                        NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
                        [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
                    }

                } else {
                    //if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                    [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
                }
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException * e) {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
            [self alertStatus:@"Sign in Failed." :@"Error!" :0];
        }
        if (success) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
        }
    }

    - (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title :(int) tag
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                            message:msg
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        alertView.tag = tag;
        [alertView show];
    }


- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

php login script

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

require_once('DbConnector.php');

$connector = new DbConnector();

$username=htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'],ENT_QUOTES);
$password=md5($_POST['password']);

$sql="SELECT id, username, password, access, name FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND enabled = '1'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

//if username exists
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    //compare the password
    if(strcmp($row['password'],$password)==0)
    {
        //now set the session from here if needed
        $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
        $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
        $_SESSION['access']=$row['access'];
        $_SESSION['name']=$row['name'];     

        //if($row['access']=='0')
        //{
        echo '{"success":1}';

 } else {
    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Username and/or password is invalid."}';
}
}else {    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Username and/or password is invalid."}';}    



?>
```

Any help with setting up the sessions and using them to send data back and forth would be awesome.

Comment: You need to add `session_start();` at the top of your php file before the call to `header()`

Comment: ok thanks i have added that, but how do I access the session variables once I am back in the app? I need to use them to populate queries in future API End Points

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the session data in your application, then you should echo it out to the page so that the application can read it back. So you could output:

```
$name = $row['name'];
echo '{"success":1, "name":"$name"}';
```

or something. If you mean that you want to be able to check whether the user is logged in or not with the application whenever they make an action, then you should just do the checks server-side when the script is called and include an error message in the JSON you return. Hope that helps!

Comment: ok so once I have echoed that data back to the app, how do I store it to make it accessible from another view? for example, on login success the app goes to a tableView that populates with user specific data, and I would need to use that data to populate that query

Comment: I tried what you said and it caused the login to be unsuccessful for one and secondly, it just echoed what i typed exactly and didn't expand the variable. any other suggestions?